# How to read a text file without showing the other language characters in R?

Tags: r

I have a .txt file looks similar to this...

```
*** Header Start ***
਍嘀攀爀猀椀漀渀倀攀爀猀椀猀琀㨀 ㄀ഀഀ
LevelName: Session
਍䰀攀瘀攀氀一愀洀攀㨀 䈀氀漀挀欀ഀഀ
LevelName: Trial
਍䰀攀瘀攀氀一愀洀攀㨀 匀甀戀吀爀椀愀氀ഀഀ
LevelName: LogLevel5
਍䰀攀瘀攀氀一愀洀攀㨀 䰀漀最䰀攀瘀攀氀㘀ഀഀ
LevelName: LogLevel7
਍䰀攀瘀攀氀一愀洀攀㨀 䰀漀最䰀攀瘀攀氀㠀ഀഀ
```

I want to read the file and remove all of the random character lines to just get the English lines as a column in a data frame. When I just read the file using read.table or readLines or scan or read delim I get a weird output do to the characters...

```
 [1] "ÿþ*" "H"   "S"   "*"   "\n"  "V"   "1"   "\n"  "L"   "S"   "\n"  "L"   "B"   "\n"  "L"   "T"   "\n" 
  [18] "L"   "S"   "\n"  "L"   "L"   "\n"  "L"   "L"   "\n"  "L"   "L"   "\n"  "L"   "L"   "\n"  "L"   "L"  
  [35] "\n"  "L"   "L"   "\n"  "E"   "G"   "\n"  "S"   "0"   "\n"  "S"   "1"   "\n"  "S"   "8"   "4"   "P"  
  [52] "\n"  "S"   "9"   "\n"  "S"   "1"   "\n"  "D"   "G"   "\n"  "R"   "-"   "\n"  "G"   "1"   "\n"  "D"
```

What can I do to fix this without manually removing the lines in all of the text files?

Comment: Do the lines in English and other language always alternate?

Comment: It seems like it's every other line. But I have multiple text files. So I am not certain it will be the same case for each file. When I try to read the file it just comes up as random letters as shown above. I want to read it as just the English lines